# Change text content after animation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, semantic-ui

Trying to perform a simple swing animation using  Semantic UI framework.
I want the text to swing, then change its content, then swing again to appear again in the screen.
The probleme is that, the changing of its content is performed before that the first swing ends, even if the instructions of changing the content are coming after.
I want it to swing -> disappear -> change its content -> swing again to appears again.
Thanks in advance...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LoginPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ExternalCSS/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ExternalCSS/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MyCSS/LoginPage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title" class="verticalDiv">
        <h1 class="pulse">SIGN IN</h1>
        <h6 style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">TO</h6>
        <h3>YOUR ACCOUNT</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="horizentalDiv">
            <button class="btn-large btn-floating waves-effect waves-light cyan"></button>
            <button class="horizentalDiv btn-large btn-floating pulse scale-transition scale-in">
    </button>
        </div>
</body>
<script src="js/ExternalJS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ExternalJS/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ExternalJS/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/MyJS/LoginPage.js"></script>
```

```
var bouttonLogin = document.querySelector("#informations button:nth-child(1)");
        bouttonLogin.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var title = document.querySelector("#title");
            $("#bouttons button:nth-child(1)").transition('jiggle');
            $("#title").transition('swing down'); // First animation
            document.querySelector("#title h1").innerHTML = "SIGN UP";
            document.querySelector("#title h6").innerHTML = "AND";
            document.querySelector("#title h3").innerHTML = "ENJOY !";
            $("#title").transition('swing down'); // Second Animation
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
bouttonLogin.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var title = document.querySelector("#title");
  $("#bouttons button:nth-child(1)").transition('jiggle');
  $("#title").transition('swing down'); // First animation
  $("#title").addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    document.querySelector("#title h1").innerHTML = "SIGN UP";
    document.querySelector("#title h6").innerHTML = "AND";
    document.querySelector("#title h3").innerHTML = "ENJOY !";
    $("#title").transition('swing down'); // Second Animation
  });
});
```

Comment: animationend instead of transitionend works like a charm (y), thanks for the answer